# Find all $Z\in C$ such that $|z|=2$ and $Im(z^6) = 8Im(z^3).$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Practice problem from a college textbook.

Find all $Z\in\mathbb C$ such that $|z|=2$ and $Im(z^6) =  8Im(z^3).$

My method is:

$2^6\sin6\phi = 8\times2^3\sin3\phi$

$\sin6\phi = \sin3\phi$

$\sin3\phi = 2\sin3\phi\cos3\phi$

$\cos3\phi = \frac{1}{2}$

$3\phi = \frac{\pi}{3} , \frac{5\pi}{3}$

Yielding:

$\phi_{1,2,3} = \frac{\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi}{3} , k=0,1,2$

$\phi_{4,5,6} = \frac{\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi}{3} , k=0,1,2$

This turned out wrong, because the solution provided by the textbook is
$z_1 = 2cis\frac{7}{9}\pi , z_2 = 2cis\frac{5}{9}\pi ,z_3 = 2cis\frac{2}{3}\pi .$
There are only three solutions according to the textbook.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Both you and your textbook forget the solution $z=2$. When you divide by $\sin (3\phi)$, you have to consider separately the case $\sin (3\phi)=0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy If $\sin(3\theta) = 0$ then $\theta$ can be $0$, $\pi/3$, $2\pi/3$, etc. right?

Comment: @shardulc yes. The general solution for $\sin (3\phi)=0$ is $\phi = k\pi/3 $, $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy So all those solutions ($\theta < 2\pi$) will be valid since the imaginary part of $z^6$ and $z^3$ will be zero.

Comment: @shardulc correct.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Thank you, that makes sense. Could you tell me if the six solutions that I found are correct, despite four of them being missing from the textbook's provided answer?

Comment: @JimmyMalone see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The key equation here, as you write, is $$\sin 6\phi-\sin3\phi=0.$$
We can apply the formula for the difference of $\sin$ functions:
$$\sin 6\phi-\sin3\phi=2\sin(3\phi/2)\cos(9\phi/2)=0,$$
which immediately gives us all possible solutions:
$$\sin(3\phi/2)=0\Rightarrow \phi = \frac 23 \pi k,\quad k\in \Bbb Z, $$
$$\cos(9\phi/2)=0\Rightarrow \phi = \frac 19 \pi  +\frac 29 \pi k,\quad k\in \Bbb Z, $$
so, by limiting $\phi$ to the interval $[0,2\pi)$ we obtain possible values
$$0,\quad\frac 23 \pi ,\quad\frac 43 \pi,$$
and
$$\frac 19 \pi,\quad   \frac 13 \pi,\quad\frac 59 \pi,\quad\frac 79 \pi,\quad \pi,\quad\frac {11}{9} \pi,\quad\frac {13}{9} \pi,\quad\frac {5}{3} \pi,\quad\frac {17}{9} \pi.$$

You can also write these solutions as 
$$0,\quad\pm\frac 23 \pi,\quad\pm\frac 19 \pi,\quad   \pm\frac 13 \pi,\quad\pm\frac 59 \pi,\quad\pm\frac 79 \pi,\quad \pi.$$

Comment: Thank you, very well explained.